# Use Autopilot to parse caller's message into an array

Tags: php, arrays, twilio, twilio-autopilot

I am new to Twilio and Autopilot and am trying to figure out how it works. With auto pilot is it possible to send multiple values to the back end server?

For example, if the caller says "Two lattes and a croissant please." (like what's in the example when creating fields), will Twilio pull out those fields into an array and send them to the redirect URL?

All I am getting is the full unprocessed string "Two lattes and a croissant please." on my php server.